# Noise inside an ACES/pumpkin suit helmet?

Tags: spacesuits, helmets, noise

As I understand it there was plenty of noise inside a NASA EVA suit helmet from fans circulating the air.

Was the Advanced Crew Escape Suit helmet for launch and reentry similarly noisy?

Comment: ACES and the earlier LES suit were to provide a minimum of protection in event of a rapid depress or toxic atmosphere event.  There’s no internal fans in either; all pressurization is provided via umbilical.   So the suits themselves are pretty quiet - the surrounding environment can still be loud as hell, but these suits aren’t contributors to the acoustic environmental load.  Don’t know what the flow rate for shuttle was and what that would provide acoustically if pressurized.